# How to insert multiple pdfpages with different size to 1 page

Tags: pdfpages

I use the package `\pdfpages` to insert multiple pdf pages to 1 page. The problem is that I have 4 squares that I want on the top of the page and 1 rectangle on the bottom. The heigth and width matches the squares but I don't know how I can fit them to 1 page? Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x3]{name_of_pdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I tried using the `\includepdf` function two times but than it is not on the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1-4,pagecommand={ \thispagestyle{empty}}, fitpaper=true, nup=2x2]{name_of_pdf.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=5,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}, fitpaper=true]{name_of_pdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To construct complex arrangements of images, I would use TikZ or a shipout hook or formerly package `eso-pic` or package `text-pos` or …

Comment: Note that pdfpages uses \includegraphics to actually implement the images.  The tricky bit is overlapping the current margins.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to arrange multiple images on a page, filling the entire page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\toppagemargin}
\newlength{\leftpagemargin}

\begin{document}
\newpage% increment page counter
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\setlength{\toppagemargin}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep}%
\ifodd\value{page}
  \setlength{\leftpagemargin}{\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin}%
\else
  \setlength{\leftpagemargin}{\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin}%
\fi
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}% fill text area
  \vspace*{-\toppagemargin}%
  \hspace*{-\leftpagemargin}%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\paperheight][t]{\paperwidth}% fill whole page
    \lineskip=0pt
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
    
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr \leftpagemargin+\textwidth-\paperwidth}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr \toppagemargin+\textheight-\paperheight}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```